# Accessing Images from image folder in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm beginner to java GUI. And want to access images from the folder but i'm getting the following error.

My Code

```
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Images {

    private static String IMG_FOLDER = "C:/Users/RASHID/workspace/images/";

    public static Image ICON = getImage(IMG_FOLDER + "icon.png");

private static Images instance; 

    private Images() {}

    public static Images getInstance() {
        if(instance==null)
            instance = new Images();
        return instance;
    }

    public static Image getImage(String image){
        return getImageIcon(image).getImage();
    }

    public static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String image){
        return new ImageIcon(getInstance().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(image));
    }
}
```

When i try to run this one in main i get the following Errors. I don't know whats happening here.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Images.getImageIcon(Images.java:38)
    at Images.getImage(Images.java:34)
    at Images.<clinit>(Images.java:9)
```

Comment: You don't use classloaders to fetch files from hard drive, only from the compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use classloaders to fetch files from hard drive. Instead, you need to fetch them as `File`s and transform to `Image`s first:

```
File sourceimage = new File("c:\\mypic.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
return new ImageIcon(image);
```

(taken directly from [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-image-from-file-or-url/) - take a look)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to construct ImageIcon object using a constroctur that takes URL paramter (because getResource() method returns URL object, and by the way in this case it returns null, hence NullPointerException)

You should use [ImageIcon(String filename)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) constructor instead, which will create ImageIcon from the file specified.

Comment: return new ImageIcon(getInstance().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(image));
I want to use this, but how can i use this one for images resides on the drive

Comment: getResource() method looks for resources in the runtime classpath (by default bin folder). You could for example add the images folder to your classpath. I think (although don't quote me on that) that there is no way to pass absolute path to this method.

Answer (score 0):

**Read from Local Folder**

```
File sourceimage = new File("c:\\picture_name.jpeg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
```